# Bringing up an interface does not add default gateway to the routing table in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, routing

I have this in my interfaces file:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 20.135.251.218
        netmask 255.255.255.252
        up route add default gw 20.135.251.217 dev eth1 metric 1
```

If I run `ifconfig eth1 down`, the default gateway is removed from the routing table. But when I do `ifconfig eth1 up`, the default gateway is not added to the routing table. I have two default gateways with different metric, so only the other gateway appears in the routing table. I have set gc_timeout as `10`. I'm trying implemet a solution mentioned in the answer to [this question.](https://superuser.com/questions/341030/i-have-both-cable-and-dsl-at-home-how-do-i-put-that-to-good-use) how can I automatically add the default gateway when I bring up the interface?

Answer (score 2):

You can better do this load balancing among multiple internet connections by using `Advanced Routing (iproute2)` feature of Linux Kernel.

By default, there are three routing tables maintained by linux kernel. You can view these three by using the following command:

```
$ ip rule list
0: from all lookup local
32766: from all lookup main
32767: from all lookup default
```

When you give `route -n` command it gives the entries of the `main` routing tables.

You can view the entries in each of these three routing tables by using the command:

```
$ ip route list tables local
$ ip route list tables main
$ ip route list tables default
```

You can add a new routing table let's say `pradeep` by using following set of commands:

```
$ echo 200 pradeep >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
$ ip rule add from all table pradeep
```

**I think you want to do exactly the same discussed here: [Routing for multiple providers](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html)**

Comment: I want to have a failover or fallback setup and not load balancing. When the main route fails, it should automatically change over to backup link.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have just finished writing some lines about dead gateway detection and neighbour unreachability for multi-homed routing setups in another question. Maybe my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53380/17800) sheds more light on the topic.