# Debian Server with 3 NIC Communicating with 3 different IP subnets

Tags: routing, network-interface, subnets

I have an ISP billing system installed on Debian GNU/Linux 8, which has 3 NIC cards. The Server is connected to 3 Mikrotik routers. Each router is connected to different internet lines which means they have 3 different static public IP subnets.

Currently the server is connected to *router1* `172.10.1.1/24` directly via eth0. the other two routers are reachable via the internet, but we have issue reaching them sometimes due to internet outage.

This is the current network [diagram](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMbiEJwcyMTytLbPYnepoUEun2tryjIEHsKSguJNoVU9YoWFi0sYHk4TlxEtLqh1w?key=enJQZEROeUNTc1hEN01QeDZ6WGRpam0yZm4zN3Jn):

[image]

I have configured `eth1` and `eth2` and connected directly to the *router2* and *router3* respectivly using the following answers/guides:

[Is it possible to have multiple default gateways for outbound connections?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345862/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-default-gateways-for-outbound-connections)

https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System

I have configured them exactly according to the above links but I was not successful yet. All the 3 networks stopped communicating, even *router1*. I have been forced to rollback.

What I would like to achieve is connecting all three routers directly to the Server so that they can communicate locally.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, which is allowing the tree routers to communicate locally via the server, you have to Enable `IP Forwarding` on that server so you can use it as a router to connect different networks together.

To do that (without rebooting the system):

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

or

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

the setting is changed instantly; the result will not be preserved after rebooting the system.

Permanent setting using /etc/sysctl.conf

If we want to make this configuration permanent the best way to do it is using the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` where we can add a line containing `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`.

Comment: Mhd thanks for your prompt answer. Should I implement first the above guideline and then enable IP forward?

Comment: @Hirmoge you welcome, The answer is in general, to make the server work as a router no matter of what you want to do.

Comment: I have enabled with out success. I cant ping either router1 or the other two when I add static IPs and enable ip forward.