# Two NICs, two gateways, multiple aliases under each

Tags: centos, networking, network-interface, route

Last year I set up a CentOS 6 machine with two NICs, each using a separate gateway.  Multiple aliases exist under NIC#1 (em1, em1:0, em1:1, ect), but currently only one interface exists under NIC#2 (em2).

I need to add an aliases to NIC#2 and am unsure how best to proceed.

Here is a quick summary of how I arrived at a working config as of now:

---

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/

```
em1
    DEVICE=em1
    NAME=siteABC
    IP=22.22.22.214
    GATEWAY=22.22.22.2
    NETMASK=255.255.255.0
    GATEWAY=22.22.22.2
    DNS1=1.1.1.1
    DNS2=1.1.1.2
    TYPE=Ethernet
    ONBOOT=yes
    BOOTPROTO=none

em1:0
    DEVICE=em1:0
    NAME=siteABC
    IPADDR=22.22.22.215
    GATEWAY=22.22.22.2
    NETMASK=255.255.255.0
    GATEWAY=22.22.22.2
    DNS1=1.1.1.1
    DNS2=1.1.1.2
    TYPE=Ethernet
    ONBOOT=yes
    BOOTPROTO=none

em2 
    DEVICE=em2
    NAME=sitetwo
    HWADDR=$MACADDRESS
    IPADDR=44.44.44.69
    NETMASK=255.255.255.0
    #GATEWAY=  ### commented out per below ###
    DNS1=1.1.1.1
    DNS2=1.1.1.2
    TYPE=Ethernet
    ONBOOT=yes
    BOOTPROTO=none
```

/etc/iproute2/rt_tables was edited to add a new line at the bottom (below #1 inr.ruhep). The new line contains 200 MGMT.

```
#
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0 unspec
#
# local
#
#1 inr.ruhep
200 MGMT
```

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-em2` was created with the following:

```
default table MGMT via 44.44.44.2

** Note that 44.44.44.2 is the gateway of the second NIC (the public WAN). **
```

Lastly, I created a rules file called `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-em2` with the following:

```
from 44.44.44.69 table MGMT
```

---

**Continued:**

The default gateway has multiple aliases configured (em1, em1:0, em1:1, ect).  The second gateway only has one interface (em2) however I need to add  alias em2:0 for another site IP hosted by the machine.

**What I've tried today**

I configured an alias called em2:0 which mirrors em2 except for DEVICE, NAME, and IPADDR.  The network restarted without a problem, but I'm not able to access the newly configured IPADDR under em2:0.

**Question**

Do I just need to add another entry in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-em2` file (shown above)?   Or is there more to do to add an alias under em2?   *This is a production system and I am hesitant to make a quick change to see what happens.*

Comment: You can only have one default gateway.  You'll need to set route(s) to other networks specifically to use your 2nd interface.

Comment: @A.B, thanks for the reminder on terminology.  I've updated the question so not to confuse anyone

Comment: I'll wait till I can be at the machine before adding the new rule.  Will follow up then.

Comment: you can have multiple default routes but one is picked at random for each packet (unless one of the routes has a lower, i.e. higher precedence, metric).  see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345862/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-default-gateways-for-outbound-connections.  but you shouldn't need to change any routing rules to add an IP address to an interface - unless the new IP is in a subnet that isn't already routed to your host or LAN segment (and even then, the new route should be on your router, not your host).

Comment: @A.B you already posted that link.  how is it relevant to anything i said?  adding a new IP within an already routed subnet to an interface does not require any routing changes.    oh, and "random" is only semi-random - the source IP address of any outgoing packet affects the interface chosen (e.g. packets with src ip in 22.22.22.0/24 will go via em1, packets from 44.44.44.0/24 will go via em2).  I glossed over that because it's not particularly relevant here - I was mostly just pointing out that the comments saying you could only have one default gateway were incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it appears you have to add a rule for the new IP 44.44.44.X on em2. That would be `ip rule add from 44.44.44.X table MGMT`.

Without rule to the MGMT table (200), the default route chosen would be `default via 22.22.22.2 dev em1`, even for this IP on em2. With this setting a customer from Internet trying to reach this new management IP would have her connection arriving at em2 from an IP with no default route (so no route) defined via em2: the default setting for [CentOS](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/53031)' [reverse path filtering](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v4.14.19#n1124) would drop the packet.

Likewise, an outgoing packet with this new IP 44.44.44.X would attempt to go to the customer via the only available default route: 22.22.22.2 on em1. It's possible (but not very relevant, the other way is already not working) that an other equipment in the path would not allow this either (eg: if 22.22.22.2 and 44.44.44.2 are going via two different Internet providers, or simply if 22.22.22.2 has no Internet connectivity).

Adding `ip rule add from 44.44.44.X table MGMT` will select this routing table when the source ip is 44.44.44.X, now selecting `default via 44.44.44.2 dev em2` from table MGMT. A packet from Internet arriving at 44.44.44.X via em2 has now its route through em2, so won't be dropped by rp_filter. An outgoing packet from 44.44.44.X will now correctly use em2 to go to Internet via 44.44.44.2.

You can easily see the difference by typing for example:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 from 44.44.44.X
```

Without the rule, you'll see the route `8.8.8.8 from 44.44.44.X via 22.22.22.2 dev em1`, with it it will switch to `8.8.8.8 from 44.44.44.X via 44.44.44.2 dev em2 table 200`