# How to properly configure routes so SSH listens on private interface and apache listens on public

Tags: routing, sshd

I have 2 network interfaces

- `eth0` - `10.100.10.207` - private
- `eth1` - `10.100.0.42` - public

Once `eth1` is added, the routes update and `ListenAddress` within `sshd_config` causes a loss of ssh connectivity.

My end goal is to set `eth0` for `sshd` and `eth1` for `apache` as it has an associated public IP.

Here's the result of `route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.100.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.100.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
10.100.10.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: How is your second interface connected? Does it have a gateway you can point at? Also, this post may be helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36085/bringing-up-an-interface-does-not-add-default-gateway-to-the-routing-table-in-ub